# Channel color distinguishing for openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

writing a code that turns an image file into grayscale was doable with just studying my textbook for a few minutes but there's an exercise that tells me to type a line of code that opens 4 different windows all each only containing 1 color red, green, blue, and original image file.

the image file that im using is the opencv logo. and here's what i wrote so far-

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Mat image = imread("C:/placeholder/opencvicon", 1);
Mat bgr[3], blue_img, green_img, red_img, zero(image.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(0));
split(image, bgr);

imshow("image", image);
imshow("blue_img", blue_img);
imshow("green_img", green_img);
imshow("red_img", red_img);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

as you can see, I need to come up with line of code that comes between "split(image, bgr);" and " imshow("image", image);". from the looks of it, it probably has to do something with separating the color channels which i think i forgot how to do. would seriously appreciate if I can get little explanation of what each function does.

Comment: What's the expected result (as in how should the red, green and blue channels be visualized -- just a grayscale image containing the particular channel, or should the red channel image be shown in shades of red, etc.)? The fact that I see the variables named `blue_img, green_img, red_img, zero`, suggests the latter, in which case you need to `merge` the separated channels back together. If it's the former, than the 4 variables are useless, and you just need to modify your calls `imshow`, to use the elements of array `bgr` that you already `split` the source image into.

Answer (score 0):

The function "split" will allocate the individual channel (B, G, R) into your Mat array bgr.
Afterwards, you need to allocate each of this to the other Mat like so:

```
split(image, bgr);

blue_img = bgr[0];
green_img = bgr[1];
red_img = bgr[2];

imshow("image", image);
imshow("blue_img", blue_img);
imshow("green_img", green_img);
imshow("red_img", red_img);
```

Comment: i try this when i can get to my work computer after i sleep but

      
       blue_img = bgr[0];
       green_img = bgr[1];
       red_img = bgr[2];


doesnt seem to work. Ill try again tomorrow tho.